# jQuery code in between the page but jQuery library in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery library in the footer to follow the good practices. It's placed right before the `</body>` tag. However, I have jQuery sortable code in the middle of the page inside a modal for some reason to sort photos. My sortable code was working this way few months back up to Oct, 2021. However, I did not look up on that part of module for some months and today it's not working. The console is returning this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Example of my code:

```html
<head>
  <title>My First page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sortPhotos">
    <ul id="sortable" class="reorder-gallery mt-3"></ul>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
          // CODE GOES HERE
        }).disableSelection();
      });
    </script>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery script elements are usually put in the head element before the body

[check here to see exactly where to place the jQuery script tag](https://learningjquery.com/2020/11/how-to-add-jquery-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to keep the right order when you are running any old javascript projects because the first script run sooner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>My First page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="sortPhotos">
    <ul id="sortable" class="reorder-gallery mt-3"></ul>
   </div>
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#sortable").sortable({
        // CODE GOES HERE
      }).disableSelection();
    });
   </script>   
  </body>
 </html>
```

Also check your jquery path.

Answer (score 0):

**Order matters**.

In your first `<script>` you try to call the `$` function and it errors because `$` isn't defined.

In your second `<script>` you load jQuery which defines `$`, but by then it is too late.

Reverse the order of your `<script>` elements.